# Linux Mint Proxy Issues

Tags: terminal, proxy, linux-mint, software-update

My issue is that I've been unable to have the terminal command `sudo apt-get upgrade` to not run on the proxy. I've tried `unset {http,https,ftp}_proxy` and `unset {HTTP,HTTPS,FTP}_PROXY` to no avail. I've also tried to set the proxy settings to none in the network settings, but it too, didn't work. Basically I would like to totally remove the proxy server from all of my settings. Sorry for being such a novice user.

In addition, the main reason why this problem is that I haven't been able to update my computer at all, or get new software from the command line. I would appreciate any and all answers that help resolve this.

If it helps, I'm running Linux Mint 13 Maya.
In addition, from terminal, when executing those commands I get `0% [Connecting to www.hidemyass.com (proxyip)]`, yet the web browsers say that I'm not behind a proxy.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It depends how you [configured](https://askubuntu.com/questions/7470/how-to-run-sudo-apt-get-update-through-proxy-in-commandline) your proxy in the first place.

You could check if you previously specified the proxy settings in an apt config file, using this:

```
grep 'https*::Proxy' /etc/apt/ -i -r
```

Alternatively, if your proxy settings were [placed in `/etc/sudoers`](https://askubuntu.com/a/19298/133393) then you can't disable them before running `sudo`.  You should either run `sudo visudo` to remove the proxy config, or disable the settings temporarily like this:

```
sudo su -
unset {http,https,ftp}_proxy
apt-get upgrade
```

Comment: With the `grep` command, it listed settings within /etc/apt/apt.conf. Should I delete all lines with Acquire::{http,https,ftp}proxy? or should I just leave the " " 's blank?

Comment: You could delete them. But I would just comment them out by putting `//` at the front of the line.